# Created Lifecycle Hook of global vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, lifecycle

I want to be able to use the AOS library globally on my vue project.

This is for Vue 2.

```
new Vue({
  created () {
    AOS.init()
  },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

The Vue 3 sets up the app a little bit different.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

I dont have that `created` option with the Vue 3 setup. I tried this, but it´s more of a guessing game...

```
createApp({App, AOS.init()})
```

But do I make this work in Vue 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still do that in Vue 3. Note `h()` is now imported as a global function from `vue` instead of being an argument of `render()`.

Here's the equivalent Vue 3 code:

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp({
  created() {
    AOS.init()
  },
  render: () => h(App),
}).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `created` hook of the root component. To me that has always seemed like an appropriate place to initialize application-wide libraries.